# Pasar un fichero ya abierto en el main como parámetro de función

Tags: c

Muy buenas a todos, tengo que decir que este programa ya lo tenía funcionando, pero por nuevas exigencias en lo que tiene que ver con los parámetros de las funciones pues me estoy volviendo un poco loco.

En sí, el problema viene con el hecho de pasar un `FILE *` como argumento a una función, pero con un pequeño detalle, y es el de tener que pasar como argumento sólo el puntero al archivo.

El enunciado sobre la función en sí dice lo siguiente:

> numLineasArchivos: se le pasa el puntero a un archivo y devuelve cuántas
> líneas tiene.

Vale, el código que me funcionaba era este:

En primer lugar, la función en sí y a continuación el main

```
int numLineasArchivos(FILE *archivo, char *nombreArch){
    
    char caracterLeido;
    int MAX_L = 0;

    //Abrimos el archivo pasado por el argumento
    archivo=fopen(nombreArch,"r"); 
    
    //Comprobamos una buena apertura
    if(archivo==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error al abrir el archivo");  
    }
    
    //Leemos todas las líneas del archivo para obtener la cantida de lineas
    while(1){
        caracterLeido = fgetc(archivo);
        
        if(caracterLeido == '\n'){
            MAX_L++;
        }
        else if(caracterLeido == EOF){
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(archivo);

    return MAX_L;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    
    const char *nombreAchivo = argv[1];
    int MAXCa;
    int MAXLi;

    FILE *archivo;
    
    //Comprobamos que los parametros sean correctos 2 porque tenemos que tener en cuenta la posición 0
    if(argc < 2 || argc > 2){
        printf("Parametros erroneos\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //Mismo razonamiento que la PR10 - Ej2 (programa.c)
    char *archivoPuntos = (char *)malloc(strlen(nombreAchivo)*sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(archivoPuntos, nombreAchivo);

    //
    MAXCa = obtenerCaracteres(archivo, archivoPuntos);
    MAXLi = numLineasArchivos(archivo, archivoPuntos);

    //Creamos el puntero de triangulos
    TRIANGULO *pTriangulo = (TRIANGULO *)malloc(MAXLi*sizeof(TRIANGULO));

    //Esta función saca en las posiciones de salida la línea completa del archivo
    leerDatos(archivoPuntos, MAXLi, MAXCa, pTriangulo);

    //Trabajamos ahora con las funciones de "filtrado por mayor"
    printf("Tendremos un total de %i triangulos, con indices de 0 a %i\n\n", MAXLi, MAXLi-1);
    printf("El indice (empezando por 0) del Triangulo con perimetro mayor sera: %i\n", mayorPerimetro(pTriangulo, MAXLi));
    printf("El indice (empezando por 0) del Triangulo con area mayor sera: %i\n", mayorArea(pTriangulo, MAXLi));

return 0;
}
```

Omito otras funciones porque o tienen el mismo problema o bien no tiene ninguno.

El caso, es que me he puesto a cambiar los parámetros y cambiar la lógica de que cada función abra, trabaje y cierre el archivo por abrir el archivo en el main y pasar ese puntero FILE que creo para almacenar la "apertura" del archivo y pasarlo como parámetro... pero nada, no lee nada, hice la prueba de que muestre un `print` al entrar en la función y entrar entra, pero al pedirle que muestre el carácter que lea con `fgetc()` y no devuelve nada.

Este es el código que tengo ahora

```
//Esta función devuelve cantidades en el archivo
int numLineasArchivos(FILE *archivo){

    char caracterLeido;
    int MAX_L = 0;
    
    //Leemos todas las líneas del archivo para obtener la cantida de lineas
    while(1){
        caracterLeido = fgetc(archivo);
        printf("%c", caracterLeido);
        
        if(caracterLeido == '\n'){
            MAX_L++;
        }
        else if(caracterLeido == EOF){
            break;
        }
    }

    return MAX_L;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    
    const char *nombreAchivo = argv[1];
    int MAXCa;
    int MAXLi;

    FILE *archivo;
    
    //Comprobamos que los parametros sean correctos 2 porque tenemos que tener en cuenta la posición 0
    if(argc < 2 || argc > 2){
        printf("Parametros erroneos\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //Mismo razonamiento que la PR10 - Ej2 (programa.c)
    char *archivoPuntos = (char *)malloc(strlen(nombreAchivo)*sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(archivoPuntos, nombreAchivo);

    //Abrimos el archivo pasado por el argumento
    archivo=fopen(archivoPuntos,"r"); 
    
    //Comprobamos una buena apertura
    if(archivo==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error al abrir el archivo");  
    }

    //
    MAXCa = obtenerCaracteres(archivo);
    MAXLi = numLineasArchivos(archivo);

    printf("%i\n", MAXLi);

    //Ya hemos sacado la info que necesitabamos del archivo en el main, lo cerramos
    fclose(archivo);

    //Creamos el puntero de triangulos
    TRIANGULO *pTriangulo = (TRIANGULO *)malloc(MAXLi*sizeof(TRIANGULO));
    
    //Esta función saca en las posiciones de salida la línea completa del archivo
    leerDatos(archivoPuntos, MAXLi, MAXCa, pTriangulo);

    //Trabajamos ahora con las funciones de "filtrado por mayor"
    printf("Tendremos un total de %i triangulos, con indices de 0 a %i\n\n", MAXLi, MAXLi-1);
    printf("El indice (empezando por 0) del Triangulo con perimetro mayor sera: %i\n", mayorPerimetro(pTriangulo, MAXLi));
    printf("El indice (empezando por 0) del Triangulo con area mayor sera: %i\n", mayorArea(pTriangulo, MAXLi));

    return 0;
}
```

Y me despista porque tengo que usar estos métodos y la función así, y es que de la otra forma funcionaba... Pero claro, aquí el profesor manda

El archivo que está leyendo es este:

```
1 2 3;3 0 0;3 5 0
2 2 0;3 2 0;3 5 0
0 0 0;3 0 0;10 15 0
```

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? Muchas gracias

-- SOLUCIÓN --

Resulta que el problema no estaba en al función de obtener las líneas, estaba en una función previa que lo que hacía era obtener los caracteres. La solución fue ir a dicha función de caracteres y añadir el rewind de ese archivo `rewind(archivo)`

```
int numCaractArchivos(FILE *archivo){
    
    rewind(archivo);

    char caracterLeido;
    int caracteresLinea = 0;
    int MAX_C = 0;
   
    //Leemos todas las líneas del archivo para obtener la cantida de lineas
    while(1){
        caracterLeido = fgetc(archivo);
        
        if(caracterLeido == '\n'){
            if(caracteresLinea > MAX_C){
                MAX_C = caracteresLinea;
            }
            caracteresLinea = 0;
        }
        else if(caracterLeido == EOF){
            break;
        }
        else{
            caracteresLinea++;
        }
    }

    return MAX_C;
}
```

Comment: prueba a ver si te funciona realizando el siguiente cambio `char *archivoPuntos = (char *)malloc((strlen(nombreAchivo)+1)*sizeof(char));` en la linea de codigo donde se reserva memoria apuntado por "archivoPuntos", si bien estas calculando cuantos espacios utilizar para la cadena de caracteres con strlen, no estas tomando en cuenta que al final de la cadena debe haber el caracter fin de cadena `\0` es por eso que esta sumando un 1, ademas, lo que vas a almacenar son caracteres de tipo char no char*

Comment: Nada, mi aún cambiando lee

Comment: otra cosa de la que me acabo de dar cuenta, es que antes de llamar a la funcion "numLineasArchivos" debes volver a posicionar el puntero interno del archivo al inicio de este, con la funcion rewind, asi `rewind(archivo);` espero te funcione, porque por lo demas veo que esta bien tu codigo

Comment: Solucionado, luego en otro momento modifico la pregunta y añado la solución. La misma pasaba por añadir el rewind dentro de la función de obtener caracteres. Muchas gracias